# How to make notify-send work on /etc/init.d/a_script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

when i write `notify-send 'test'` in /etc/init.d/a_script, i can't see any notify. see following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:    someone
# Required-Start:  $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:  $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   0 6
# Short-Description:  OpenBSD Secure Shell sv
### END INIT INFO
## Fill in name of program here.

case "$1" in
start)
notify-send 'test'
exit 0
;;

stop)
exit 0
;;
reload|restart|force-reload)
exit 0
;;
restart_for_debug)
exit 0
;;
**)
echo "usg: $0 {start|stop|restart|restart_for_debug}" 1>&2
exit 1
;;
esac
```

**my question is:** how to make above code short notify with `sudo service this_script start`

Answer (score 1):

`notify-send` communicates over D-Bus so it needs a D-Bus address to work. The address is not preserved when you call startup scripts using `service`. The following commands retrieve the address of the selected user's session:

```
user=username
dbusaddr1="$(
    grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS= "/proc/$(pgrep -u "$user" gnome-session | head -n1)/environ" |
    sed -e 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//' )"
```

Then you can call `notify-send` with the address. You have to change the user because it does not work under `root`:

```
su "$user" -c "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=\"$dbusaddr1\" notify-send 'test'"
```

You can find some additional information in this article: [How to write udev rules](http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/)